# Webview clicks not opening up links (Works in emulator not Device)

Tags: android, webview

So as you can read form the title, that is the problem I am facing. All is well when I click the links from my webView in the emulator but when I transition into my phone, nothing happens when it is clicked. Here is what I have so far.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.main_selection_tab);

    dbh = new MyDBHandler(this);

    String url = "http://somelinkhere.com";

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    addTabsOnCreate();
    populateBodypartListView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone an htc? As far as i know htc didn't pay for patents and you cannot click links on certain devices.

Comment: Its a samsung s4 :(, what puzzles me is how it works fine it my emulator but not my device.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain how it works in emulator and not working in actual devices. But it seems you have to override **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** method in webviewclient.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return  false;
        }
    });
```

return false means this webview will handle the urls.
more details [from doumentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))